# NOT Required field throws error 'This field is required'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm usin django 1.6.1 final version and python 2.7. I've created an Form Model:

```
class EditUserForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='', required=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль',
            'class': 'form-control', }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='', required=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Подтверждение пароля',
            'class': 'form-control', }))

    email = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail',
            'class': 'form-control', }))

    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Телефон',
            'class': 'form-control', }))
```

When I submit this form and try to call `is_valid()` method it throws errors `This field is required` if either `password1` or `password2` is left empty (but it's set to `required=False`?). If I try to set `blank=True` it throws an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'`. What's the problem?

Comment: Where did you put the `blank=True` exactly?

Comment: I put it into the Field constructor

Comment: Form fields are not database fields; what do you do with the form information? What is the full traceback for the `This field is required` error?

Comment: The `required=False` should certainly work for for the `forms.CharField()` instances, but I suspect that the exception you see comes from a *different* location.

Comment: Make sure blank=True is on model "If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, required=True." You can have null=True on the model and then later you can make that field mandatory on form. But you can not make a field optional in form when it is mandatory on model that will result in database error later on.